# Disabled ComboBox looks enabled on Win7

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, combobox

In our project we are using many forms and controls. One of our forms is displayed with many included controls. All controls are ought to be disabled when the form is displayed for the first time (there is an extra "edit"-button").

But my `ComboBoxes`look like they are enabled. They don't behave like this - you can't click them, no events are fired. They are actually correctly drawn if there is a draw event fired, e. g. resizing of the window.

This behaviour is only on Windows 7 - not on Windows XP. What can I do to have my comboboxes drawn correctly? It's not happening everytime, so I think it's not a problem of my comboboxes... ...it also happens that a few comboboxes are drawn correctly and the rest is drawn wrong!

[image: Wrong drawn combobox on the left - correctly drawn on the right hand side]

What can I do to avoid this?

**UPDATE:** I just found out that this behaviour only happens, when in Windows 7 another theme than "classic" is chosen.

I also debugged me throught the WindowMessages and found out, that some Messages get lost/are not send. I would show you the different readings, but the files are few hundred lines long :/

In classic all is drawn correctly. What can cause this behaviour??

**UPDATE2:** Maybe just a little update - after I activated DoubleBuffering for the whole Application (using WS_EX_COMPOSITED in the mainform) the behaviour doesn't exist any more. But it' still strange, isn't it?

Comment: Hard to say without your code. Works fine for simple test apps.

Answer (score 0):

If a paint event fixes it, you can force a redraw by calling

`this.Invalidate()`;

Comment: Sure. But the problem is only sometimes, not always, and this solution would be everything but "clean"...

Comment: Do you set them disabled in the designer? Or on some other event? Perhaps that event inst firing as you expect?

Comment: I also thought first of an event-problem or something similiar, but  I tried changing almost everything involved and still no change. Also that it just "looks" enabled and that it's working sometimes (and always on XP) got me thinking of other reasons...